# good way to speedup my R code from for loop

Tags: r, search

I have a long vector, say `x` with length of `1e6` and a same length weight vector, `w`. I want to find a small `number (i.e., a scalar value)` which will be added to each element of `x`, and make my expression value, shown in the code part below, as small as possible.

I tried using a vector from -1 to 1 by = 0.001 and using for loop to get the minimal result of my expression, but my solution is a good way to do since I will repeat the same operation 100 times or more (sometimes, the `x` length arrive to 1e7 or more), which take long time to finish.

```
getSigmoid <- function(x) {return(1 / (1 + exp(-x)))}

x <- rnorm(1e6)
w <- rnorm(1e6)
pool <- seq(-1, 1, by = 0.001)
npool <- length(pool)
result <- rep(NA, times = npool)

stime <- Sys.time()
for (i in 1:npool) {
  cat("i: ", i, "/", npool, "\n")
  flush.console()

  result[i] <- abs(sum(getSigmoid(x + pool[i]) * w) / sum(w) - 0.5)
}
etime <- Sys.time()
(spenttime <- etime - stime)
idx_min <- which.min(result)
cat("minimal value is: ", result[idx_min], "\n")
cat("solution is: ", pool[idx_min], "\n")
```

I hope to get a better solution (i.e., improve the computation speed) for my question. I tried to think the vecterization idea I can not figure out. I understand parallel is a method to try, but actually the code is already in the parallel function (i.e, nested parallel may be more difficult). So if someone can figure out a method which is based on the vectorization or other, that will be very helpful.

Comment: Well, repeating sum(w) seems wasteful. It’s also unclear whether 0.5 should be in the denominator.

Comment: You're doing 1-dimensional optimization, use `optimize()`. It will be a lot smarter than your grid search.

Comment: @42 0.5 is just put there, not in denominator. @Gregor thank you. I learned that`optimize()` is better as shown in the answer. Initially I can not think the optimization solution but just grid search naively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of calculating the entire vector space and finding the minimum, you will need to use a better search method or an optimization routine.
Base R has the function `optimize` which can do this.

```
set.seed(1234)

x <- rnorm(1e6)
w <- rnorm(1e6)

stime <- Sys.time()
  sumw<-sum(w)  #Perform the calculation once and store
  #create functions:
  getSigmoid <- function(x) {return(1 / (1 + exp(-x)))}
  f <-function(pool) {
    abs(sum(getSigmoid(x + pool) * w) / sumw - 0.5)
  }

  #optimize function performs the search
  print(optimize(f, c(-1, 1), tol = 0.00001))
etime <- Sys.time()
print(spenttime <- etime - stime)
```

Using the built-in function improves the resolution of the result and greatly improved the performance.  Your algorithm took about 30 seconds on my machine, the `optimize` function took about 0.3 secs, about 100x improvement.

The another alternative is the non-linear minimization function: `nlm`.  Same code above but substitute `nlm(f, 0)` in for the `optimize` function.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is a perfect solution.